# Pandas transformation: one-to-many relationship into one-to-one

Tags: pandas, list, one-to-many

I have a pandas dataframe such that

```
               APP_ID               SETTING_ID
0                 7              [1009, 962, 430]
1                 8              [103, 914, 890, 218]
```

I need to transform it such that each `SETTING_ID` in the list has one-to-one relationship with the `APP_ID`

```
               APP_ID          SETTING_ID
0                 7              1009
1                 7              962
2                 8              103
3                 8              914
4                 8              890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so called `unnest`

```
pd.DataFrame({'APP_ID':df.APP_ID.repeat(df.SETTING_ID.str.len()),'SETTING_ID':sum(df.SETTING_ID.tolist(),[])})
Out[367]: 
   APP_ID  SETTING_ID
0       7        1009
0       7         962
0       7         430
1       8         103
1       8         914
1       8         890
1       8         218
```

Comment: They really need to add an `unnest` function :P

Comment: @user3483203 yep, it is better have that function!  Ps: if you knowing R there is unnest function there:-)

Comment: @Wen Can always count on you for my pandas queries :)